# i get an error saying Flutter SDK path not found

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxLZ5.png)

I keep on getting this error while trying to install flutter does anyone have a solution?

I was trying to install flutter but i keep on facing this error

Comment: Check this https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Add the path from your flutter doctor output to a new System Variable

Answer (score 0):

You have two copies of the Flutter SDK:

- C:\Users\SOUMYDEEP\flutter
- D:\Software\flutter_windows.3.7.6-stable\flutter

There is a mismatch between the one being run (or used by your project) and the one first in your `PATH` environment variable.

If you don't need both, I would suggest removing one of the SDKs (to avoid confusion) and making sure the remaining one is then in your `PATH` environment variable.